# why does print 2++3 print 5 in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and I read that there is no ++ operator in Python but I am not able to understand the below code.

```
>>>print (2++3)
>>>5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`+` and `-` act as unary as well as binary operators. So,

- `a ++ b` is same as `a + (+b)`
- `a -+ b` is same as `a - (+b)`
- `a -- b` is same as `a - (-b)`
- `a +- b` is same as `a + (-b)`

As can be seen below

```
>>> 2++3
5
>>> 2-+3
-1
>>> 2--3
5
>>> 2+-3
-1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the ++ operator. Your code is interpreted as follows:

```
2 + (+3)
```

Now since +3 is 3, the final result is 5. For fun, try the following:

- 2++++++++++++++3
- 2+++++++++++++++++++++-8

See [Expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html) for details.